# MouseInfo returning coordinates that do not work for the Robot class

Tags: java

I am teaching a class about scripting and in one of my workshops we are using `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()` in addition to `Robot.mouseMove()` in order to move the mouse to specific points on the screen and "click". This works for most students computers however on others the number from the MouseInfo function does not seem to be in the same coordinate system that the Robot.mouseMove() method sees.

We are using MouseInfo to make it easier to click a specific spot on the screen using the Robot class.

We are currently running a UI-less application so most students are running it with the run button in the IDE of their choice. Does anyone know why this discrepancy might be happening on some computers or if there is a more robust way to be doing this?

Some students have said that the scale factor of their computer is affecting the behavior of the MouseInfo method but they can't find a "perfect" scale factor that works for everything.

Comment: Not sure, but It may be due to different screen resolutions.